# Can there be food during the Chuppah?

Tags: food, wedding

I was wondering if there a prohibition to have food during the Chuppah? A friend told me he thinks it's not allowed.

I wanted to have something cute and small that is meaning full to us that everyone (the people siting and observing) could enjoy during the ceremony

Comment: Interesting idea. Make sure you consult with your own rabbi before implementing ideas you see on this site.

Comment: I see alot of candies being given out by thr chupah. It shuts the people up for the ceremony:)

Comment: There is food at the kabolas ponim before the ceremony and at the reception after the ceremony. It reminds me of the Rabbi at a hotel after the guests had fallen upon the kiddush like locusts who announced without a trace of irony in his voice, "lunch is served, you must be starving".

Comment: @msh210 Thanks, I will must definitely ask the rabbi about how he feels about this.

Comment: @Mennyg That is a good point.  I had not thought about that but I like it its true that will it have that effect.